# How do I send SMS messages through graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to send an SMS message from my facebook application so that the user get an SMS informing her of updates (if there is any) in my application.

Does anyone know if graph api supports this?

Comment: Is there anything you have tried so far that didn't work and you would like to ask about?

Comment: no i didnt try cox i have no idea weather its available in graph api or not vn i come to know that its possible i ll certainly try.do u have any idea??if so plz share it thanQ...

Comment: There is definitely an 'sms' permission documented, but I've scoured the docs and I can't see anything that allows you to send SMS messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered by Facebook staff last year - [SMS through Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524694/sms-through-facebook-graph-api)

I'd say that SMS API functionality is dead.