# SMS through Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sms

There apparently was a time when it was possible to [send a Facebook user an SMS via the REST API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/sms.send/)... but I can't seem to find a way to do this on the newer Graph API. Am I missing something or has this been permanently deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's currently no graph API equivalent; I'm not sure the REST API call works anymore either

Comment: Is there a way to send SMS using Facebook currently or the only option left is to use a third-party service like Twilio?