# SMS via Facebook application

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sms

I've been looking for any example or documentation about sending sms through facebook API but couldn't find official one.

I've also read some somewhere that SMS has been deprecated from facebook API. Then why is it still available in extended permissions?

Here's some documentation about it on facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/sms.send/

Looking for answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a warning on the [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/) website,

> We are in the process of deprecating the REST API. If you are building
>   a new Facebook app, please use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). While there is still
>   functionality that we have not ported over yet, the Graph API is the
>   center of Facebook Platform moving forward and where all new features
>   will be found.

And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053723/how-do-i-send-sms-messages-through-graph-api) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524694/sms-through-facebook-graph-api) Stackoverflow questions, there is no implementation available right now.